# Part replace a record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

I need to mask data in my tables, for example data like:

```
ABCDEFG
XYZABCD
LMNOPQR
```

Should appear like:

```
AB*****
XY*****
LM*****
```

What update query can I use? Also, can I use a single query for updating multiple columns?

Comment: What database system are you using? The answer to the second question is yes, look at the documentation of `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 0):

You can just mask it when showing the data

```
select stuff(stuff(stuff(col,3,3,'*'),7,3,'*'),10,3,'*')) as col from table
```

Comment: Remove Extra bracket ')' and out put to query like this AB* XY* LM*

Comment: No dbms specified, and STUFF is product specific. Please specify which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh that was for MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the column you want to mask is called `column` from table `table`, than you can use the following query, which is standard in SQL, to *update* the value in the column:

```
update table
set column = substring(column from 1 for 2) || '****';
```

If on the other hand you want only to *select* the values to show them, you can use the following query:

```
select substring(column from 1 for 2) || '****'
from table;
```